# Forward ICMP to a tun interface

Tags: networking, routing, ping, tunnel

I’m creating a ICMP over DNS program.

Here is what works: I read tun0 interface, fragment and send to the server the ping (tunneling), process the ping on the server, get the answer and tunnel and send it back to tun0. The problem is, I need to redirect all ping request that I make from cmd to tun0 so the request can be processed.

I have looked on several topics here but the IP tables rules with IP forwarding don t seem to work. So i understand how packets works but I don’t understand how they behave between the user and the interfaces.

The only partial solution that I found is adding a static route that redirect 192.168.1.0/24 to tun0 for example, with this I see pings for this subnet on tun0 but the answers don’t go back to the terminal.

Have you got an idea?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be forwarding those packets to the tunnel interface at all. Your tun0 is only supposed to be the "front end" where the inner packets enter and exit the tunnel.

The "back end" of the tunnel should directly pick up packets from the real network interface. For ICMP, you can do so using "IP raw sockets":

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1 /* ICMP */);
```